# Remove part of file name in multiple sub directories

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, rename

The main folder "Main" contains multiple subfolders (6900,159, 9997, ...) and each subfolder contains 8 items (4 files (6900Log.final.out, 6900Log.out, 6900Log.progress.out, 6900SJ.out.tab), 3 folders (6900_STARgenome, 6900_STARpass1, 6900_STARtmp), and one compressed file (6900Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam)). The 6900_STARtmp contain further subfolders but I don't want to change name of sub folders present in 6900_STARtmp. Please see the image

[image: see Image]

I want to remove 6900 from (6900Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam, 6900Log.final.out, 6900Log.out, 6900Log.progress.out, 6900SJ.out.tab) and 6900_ from (6900_STARgenome, 6900_STARpass1, 6900_STARtmp)

So that the names of files should be (Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam, Log.final.out, Log.out, Log.progress.out, SJ.out.tab, STARgenome, STARpass1, STARtmp).

I have tried to run the below script on ubntu (18.04.3 LTS) to rename SJ.out.tab and was planning to do it for rest of files but it didn't work for me:

```
for filename in Main/*/*SJ.out.tab; do 
    #echo $filename
    describer=$(echo ${filename})        
    #mv "$filename" "${filename//${describer}/SJ.out.tab}"
done
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please indicate operating system and, if Linux, what shell you are using. You script attempt looks like `bash` under Linux, but you should still state and tag the OS.

Comment: I'd probably just use, `for f in Main/*/* ; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | sed "s/^[0-9]*_*//") ; done`. That would also change something like `123___abc.out` to `abc.out` which I am assuming is Ok. Unless you use extended globbing feature, I don't think you can write a single glob pattern that represents an arbitrary string of digits at the beginning of a file name.

Comment: I have tried to use for f in Main/*/* ; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | sed "s/^[0-9]*_*//") ; done but I am getting this error for files (6900Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam, 6900Log.final.out, 6900Log.out, 6900Log.progress.out, 6900SJ.out.tab) mv: 'star_output_first/6900/6900SJ.out.tab' and 'star_output_first/6900/6900SJ.out.tab' are the same file. And this error for files (6900_STARgenome, 6900_STARpass1, 6900_STARtmp)
mv: cannot move 'star_output_first/6900/6900_STARgenome' to a subdirectory of itself, 'star_output_first/6900/6900_STARgenome/6900_STARgenome'
m

Comment: Sorry I forgot to take the path into account: `for f in Main/*/* ; do mv "$f" $(echo "$f" | sed "s/\/^[0-9]*_*/\//") ; done`. Also, are there subfolders under `Main/*/*`?

Comment: I have tried this one but still getting the same error, yes there are around 700 subfolders inside the main folder and further, each subfolder contains 8 files. For example for a file (6900Log.out) present in a subfolder, its path is like Main/6900/6900Log.out and for file (6900SJ.out.tab), its path is like Main/6900/6900SJ.out.tab

Comment: I'm asking if there are subfolders under below `Main/*/*` (the last `*` might have some folders?) If there are, than additional checks are needed, or you can use `find`: `find Main/*/* -depth 1 -type f -exec mv {} "$(echo {} | sed "s/\/^[0-9]*_*/\//") \;` if you don't want to descend the folders further than `Main/*/*`.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding, yes 6900_STARgenome, 6900_STARpass1, 6900_STARtmp are folder names and 6900_STARtmp contain further subfolders but I don't want to change the names of subfolders present inside the 6900_STARtmp.

Comment: Ok that's a critical constraint. You should edit your question and indicate that. Check the `find` command I showed in my last comment. You should look at the manual page for `find` and understand what it's doing before running it.

Comment: Many thanks, i will read about find, In this find command (find Main/*/* -depth 1 -type f -exec mv {} "$(echo {} | sed "s/\/^[0-9]*_*/\//") \;), the quoted string should be end at some point, can you please modify it?

Comment: `find Main/*/* -depth 1 -type f -exec mv {} $(echo {} | sed "s/\/^[0-9]*_*/\//") \;`

Comment: I have already tried this option but I am still  getting this eror find: paths must precede expression: `1'

Comment: Check the man page for `find` on your system and make sure it supports the depth option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure you do not accidentally modify other files or directories, you should make sure your script restrict itself to ONLY *files* staring with the same digits as the directory name or directories starting with the number and an underscore, and ONLY one layer deep.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare    base_dir=/path/to/Main

cd ${base_dir}
while read subdir; do
  number=${subdir#./}
  for file in $(find ${subdir} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "${number}*"); do
    mv ${file} ${subdir}/${file##./${number}/${number}}
  done
  for file in $(find ${subdir} -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "${number}_*"); do
    mv ${file} ${subdir}/${file##./${number}/${number}_}
  done
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex './[0-9]*')
```

Comment: Did you missed "!" in the first line, isn't it should be like #!/bin/bash, secondly I am running this script inside the "Main" folder and got two errors: ./renaming_mapped_data: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'     and this error ./renaming_mapped_data: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: Yes. I missed the '!' In the first line (now corrected). I suspect a cut/paste error in your local copy of the script. There is no single quote on line 8 of my version. The error on line 14 is a side-effect of the error on line 8.

Comment: I just noticed another typo on line 6: `sub_dir` should be `subdir` (now corrected).

Comment: I don't know why I am getting this sort of error msgs:  mv: cannot create regular file '/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam': Permission denied
mv: cannot create regular file '/Log.final.out': Permission denied

Comment: See my previous comment.  There was a typo on line 6. I have corrected it.

Comment: Yes, I am using the updated script, by modifying the path for Main folder (base_dir=/media/waqas/waqas_third/Main) but still getting an error of permission denied (mv: cannot create regular file '/Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam': Permission denied)

Comment: I am SOOOO sorry.  When I tested the script, I did not include the 'mv' commands as I did not want to actually change any filenames. I just double-checked the script above and found another incorrect variable name. On lines 9 and 12, please change `${dir}` to `${subdir}`. I have now corrected this in the Answer.